# Eliminating ^ and $ in pattern matching

Tags: bash, wildcards

Am using the following `regex condition`, with `^` and `$` to represent the start and end of the given pattern.

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then
```

I have also written the equivalent `glob condition`

```
if [[ "$1" == ^+([[:digit:]])$ ]]; then
```

Because I have seen some people going without the use of `^` and `$`, what is the reason for eliminating them?

Comment: `^` and `$` are not glob special characters. See [3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) in the manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second expression doesn't match integers. Did you try it?

```
word=123
if [[ "$word" == ^+([[:digit:]])$ ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
```

Output

```
no
```

This is because with a shell glob the `==` requires the entire pattern to match the string, so `^` and `$` are not required. Let's try again, first with a literal `^` and `$` surrounding the value:

```
word='^123$'
if [[ "$word" == ^+([[:digit:]])$ ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
```

Output

```
yes
```

and now without the `^` and `$` mentioned anywhere:

```
word=123
if [[ "$word" == +([[:digit:]]) ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
```

Output

```
yes
```

Just to be sure, let's check several strings:

```
for word in 123 a123 123b 12c3
do
    if [[ "$word" == +([[:digit:]]) ]]
    then
        match=yes
    else
        match=no
    fi
    printf "%s:\t%s\n" "$word" "$match"
done
```

Output

```
123:    yes
a123:   no
123b:   no
12c3:   no
```